# Adding an Info Button to an iPad menu - there is already a Popover and Add button

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have a UITableView for an iPad app. On the left is the Popover button and on the right is an Add button.

Is it possible to add another button (info) to the menu bar?

If so, examples would be most welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add more than one button on each side of navigation bar, but you can add a custom view that has two or more buttons which would look and work the same way. Check out UIBarButtonItem's [initwithCustomView:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithCustomView%3a) method.

Comment: I finally decided to use a navigation bar with segmented controls. (See the Apple NavBar sample). It looks elegant and is easy to install..